# Domain-joined clients local Administrators group lost Domain Admins member: recovery possible?

Tags: filesystems, dfs-r, administrative-privileges

On a number of Windows 10 clients joined to a Windows Server 2022 domain and after some serious GPO-related mishandling, the local administrators group contains only the (inactive) administrator. Is it possible to bring back domain admins into the local administrator group? Do note that most of the clients are bitlocker-enabled, so I can not simply enable the inactive administrator account and add the domain admins from there...

So far I have tried the following:

1. Created a GPO that updates the local administrator group to include the domain admins (modified Computer Configuration -> Control Panel Settings -> Local Users and Groups -> Group (Name: Administrators built-in) -> Administrators (built-in)(Order:1) -> Local Group to add mydomain\Domain admins). gpupdate /force on the clients seems to proceed successfully, no errors are logged in the system section of event viewer, but the group is not added: [image: screenshot]
2. Created a GPO that does the same thing by using restricted groups (modified Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Restricted Groups) as per this [image]. Same result.
3. We have a remote access solution in place for these clients, that allows us to edit the registry. I modified HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList to include an existing local (non-domain) user and gave it a value of 1 (supposedly that would add the user to the local administrators group). Failed again.

Perhaps in order for GPOs to be actually executed, the client should include Domain admins in the local administrators?

**EDIT**: it seems that policy processing happens just fine, the  issue was with the group policies of our 2 DCs: they had a different view of which GPOs existed (even though repadmin/dcdiag showed no issues whatsoever). Deleted the offending ones from both sides and following approach #2 above (ie via restricted groups) worked just fine.

Since I'm looking for a "permanent" solution (removing the restricted groups policy will most likely remove the domain admins from the local admin group as well), I'd like to have #1 operational again. I can't make it work though.

**EDIT 2:** Solved this by removing the restricted groups policy and implementing a simple GPO-based powershell script, including a single `Add-LocalGroupMember` to include domain admins in the administrators group.

Comment: `Perhaps in order for GPOs to be actually executed, the client should include Domain admins in the local administrators?` No. Domain Admins is never needed. It's actually a best practice to not use it, but a group that is separate from AD, for adding to the local administrators and to let Windows manage and rotate the local administrator account.

Comment: `gpupdate /force on the clients seems to proceed succesfully,` No, It isn't possible to update computer policy without elevated permissions. Sounds like you haven't waited for policy to apply.

Comment: Where is your GPO linked? Are you using Security Filtering on the GPO? What does gpresult show?

Comment: After some hours of having examined everything, the issue was isolated to the fact that our two DCs had a different idea of what was on sysvol, even though most diagnostics showed that everything was fine, replication-wise. Will update info in the question, even though I still can't push users/groups to the local admin group using approach #1 above.

Comment: "No, It isn't possible to update computer policy without elevated permissions": running gpupdate as a normal user always told me that computer policy update completed succesfully. Furthermore, on the client I used for tests, I only had to invoke gpupdate for this restricted groups GPO to take effect; no reboot took place.

Comment: @joeqwerty the GPO was linked to the correct OU and no security filtering. Before finding the issue between the DCs, gpresult /R on the client did not show the policy. After fixing the problem I can see that gpresult /scope computer /z the system finally got the gpo.

Comment: In this discussion, the problem has now switched from "restoring domain admins back to local admins", to "how I can make the change permanent" (ie making the domain admins stick if I remove the restricted groups gpo. Would it be a good idea to rephrase the entire discussion to do so or not?

Comment: Removing the Restricted Groups GPO will revert the group membership to it's previous state. So either leave the Restricted Groups GPO in place, or use GPP to populate the group, or manually populate the group. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/add-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: 'or use GPP to populate the group': problem is that this (#1 above) does not work for some reason. Will try to do the same thing with a GPO-based powershell script.

Comment: `they had a different view of which GPOs existed (even though repadmin/dcdiag showed no issues` AD replication does not affect Group Policy replication on SYSVOL. It seems there are DFSR issues (or someone tinkering with SYSVOL files).